# Layout is not calling correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template, header

I am creating a **custom module**, everything is working fine but on **view page**, My **phtml** file calling first and then **header** is coming.

I am calling and setting data like this :

`IndexController.php`

```
class MagePeople_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
     {

          $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
     }


    public function editMeasurementAction()
    {   
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();

        $proid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('proid');
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/usermeasurement')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter( 'product_id', $proid );
        $collection->addFieldToFilter( 'user_id', $customerId );
        $collection->getFirstItem()->getData();


        foreach ($collection as $collect) {
            $response[]     = array(
            'proid'         => $collect->getProductId(),
            'stnd_size'     => $collect->getStndSize()
            );
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()
                    ->setBody($this->getLayout()
                            ->createBlock('mymodule/measurescreen')
                            ->setData('response', $collect)
                            ->toHtml());
        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
} 

Block file function is below :

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('mymodule/measurescreen.phtml');     
    }
```

I am not sure how to call block and set and retrieve data if I follow another approach.
Can someone please tell me what is wrong in this and why it is showing like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like this:

**app/code/local/Company/Module/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Company_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
        ...
        </global>
        <frontend>
        <layout>
           <updates>
               <company_module>
                   <file>company_module.xml</file> //we will define your phtml in this file
               </company_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/{packagename}/{modulename}/layout/company_module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <rooterName_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template> //or 2columns-left.phtml, ...
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="block/type" name="my.block.page" template="custom/measurescreen.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </rooterName_index_index>
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/{packagename}/{modulename}/template/custom/measurescreen.phtml**

```
<div class="wrapper">Good morning</div>
```

Comment: it is exactly same as you defined.

Comment: Not at all look a little your controller and the mine, please try my solution if you want to solve your problem

Comment: I have edited with complete code of indexcontroller of mine. Please check now.
I have done what you mentioned already.

Comment: The problem I am facing that to use setTemplate and setData together.
Whatever solution I am trying is either displaying perfect layout or my phtml file's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
           $this->loadLayout();  
           $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()
                               ->createBlock('mymodule/measurescreen')
                               ->setData('response', $collect)
                               ->toHtml()); 
           $this->renderLayout(); 


           protected function _construct()
           {
               parent::_construct();
               $this->setTemplate('mymodule/measurescreen.phtml');     
           }
```

Try this code please

Comment: Have tried this already. Not working.

Comment: change to _toHtml()

Comment: It gives error. doesn't work